# Qt 5.1.1 touch precision is not accurate

Tags: qt, qt5, qtgui, qtwayland

Issue I am facing with Qt 5.1.1 applications is that, the touch precision on the widgets are not accurate and I need to touch a little bit above the actual widget area to trigger the event (clicked).

In order to make the touch interface work, I am using 1920x1080 resolution and 11 inch display. Software - Qt  -5.1.1, Wayland - 1.1.0 and qtwayland plugin.

Any clue where the thing might go wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your screen is properly calibrated.

Comment: How can I calibrate the screen? Any mechanism provided by Wayland or QT or Linux Kernel ??

Comment: Not sure, Qt definitely doesn't provide it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Wayland to render your application, i.e. launch application by *-platform wayland* option, the coordinates of touch event is provided by compositor(e.g. weston)via wayland protocol, therefore you should check those coordinates grabbed by compositor.

You can use [debug tool](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/tools.html) provided by libinput to find what is wrong.

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”